# I need help using indexof () on arduino

Tags: json, arduino, indexof

I have  managed to get the data in a string I need from coinbase api https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json

but I can only get the dollar price, using indexOf("rate_float");
which returns the first rate_float, but how can I get the rate float of the euro?

```
  // Get rate as float
  int rateIndex = jsonAnswer.indexOf("rate_float");
  String priceString = jsonAnswer.substring(rateIndex + 12, rateIndex + 18);
  priceString.trim();
  float price = priceString.toFloat();
```

Comment: use ArduinoJson library to process the JSON

Comment: yes it is what I am doing

Comment: it doesn't look like you ar using it. you would get the "EUR" object and then read the "rate_float" property of that object. something like `root["bpi"]["EUR"]["rate_float"]`